# The best way to group range of arrays by any common element

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

Assume we have an integer arrays:

`[0,4] [1,3] [3,4] [2,5]`

I need to combine small arrays into one if there is at least one common element, for example:

`[1,2] and [2,3]` are mergeable and should give `[1,2,3]`

`[1,4] and [2,3]` are not mergeable.

The result of the initial input should be:

`[0,1,3,4] [2,5]`

Note, Interval is not criteria to merge.
I believe it is one of the theoretical problems, and this has already optimized the solution (Assuming I have a large number of small input arrays).

Thanks in advance beforehand!

Comment: You can sort each small array individually (if they are not sorted) and then sort the whole array based on starting point (first element in small array) and ending points (last element of small array). Then if the starting point of small array i+1 is smaller or equal to end point of small array i, they belong to the same interval...

Comment: Define "*adjacent element*"

Comment: Treat the numbers as vertices in a graph, and the small arrays as edges. Then find the [connected components in the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).

Comment: If 'adjacent' is supposed to mean 'sharing a common element', and repeated unions are allowed, this is the standard connected components/ union-find problem, as noted above. The problem is currently unspecified, since the first comment solves a distinct problem for another valid interpretation of 'adjacent'

Comment: @user1984,  The criteria to merge - two small arrays should have at least one common element. Interval is not criteria... For example: `[1,4]` and `[2,3]` are not mergeable.
Is it still make sense to sort?

Comment: @kcsquared, `If 'adjacent' is supposed to mean 'sharing a common element', and repeated unions are allowed, this is the standard connected components/ union-find problem` - yeah, it is.
The problem is to find all unions. Two small arrays may not have common element `[1,2]` `[3,4]`, but if there is another small array `[2,3]`, that contains one value from the first array and one value from the second array, I should merge this three arrays.
@user3386109 - You're right it is like a graph connection. Probably there is some ready-efficient algorithm on any programming lang that helps me?

Comment: This is the union find algorithm. With path compression you gen an amortized linear solution .